# Alert user that mail submission make take a few seconds to complete

Tags: php, phpmailer, wait

PHPMailer page takes a number of seconds to complete before going to success page.  Is there a way to let the user know that it may take a few seconds to "send the mail"?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                    
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $user;
$mail->Password = "$password;
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->AddAddress($uemail);
$mail->Subject = $mailsub;
$mail->Body    = $mailmsg;

$mail->Send()

header('location: genmsg.php?tp=confirm&email='.$uemail);
```

Comment: I believe that would be something you would want to do in your UI code wherever it is that you call this PHP. PHP itself can't pop a message it's server side.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!!
Basically, on submit, I use a JS function to hide the form and show a previously hidden  div asking the user to wait while the request is being submitted.

Added this code the the JS FormValidation function:

```
document.getElementById('mailform').style.display  = "none"
document.getElementById('mailing').style.display = "block"
```

When the PHPmailer finishes executing, the user is the redirected to the success page.

( The PHPmailer does take about 3 seconds to execute and then redirect on my server)

Worked perfectly!!!

Comment: When sending via SMTP to localhost, it should send in a few tens of milliseconds, not 3 seconds. Enable debug logging in PHPMailer and see what is taking the time. Check your mail server logs too.

Comment: I did some research and found this is an issue with phpmailer on shared hosting platforms with inmotionhosting.  Not an issue with VPS, but not going the invest in a vps yet.. At least I found a solution.